# jQuery, printThis print page looks different with how it looks like on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printthis

I do have a dialog that should be printable.

So I used printThis plug-in.

However, when I try to print this page, it looks different with what it looks like on display.

I do have three tables in the dialog.

[image]

As you can see in the following, height of cells of table 2 and table 3 get changed in print preview.  And it actually prints like this.

[image]

Following is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="clear bttn" id="divSmallDate">
    <div class="bttn rig floatNone">
        <button type="button" class="ui-button print_ui btnPrintPay">Print</button>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button blank btnClosePay">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
<form id="formUpdateDoc">
<div class="data">
    <div id="printArea">
    <div style="padding:5px 0 8px 0;">
        <p style="color: black; border:0; text-align:center; font-size:32px; font-family:Trebuchet MS,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif"></p>
        <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" id="payTitle" class="test" style="border:0; text-align:center; font-size:32px; font-family:Trebuchet MS,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif">
    </div>
    <table class="paytbl" style="margin:0 auto;">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 170px;">
            <col style="width: 230px;">
            <col style="width: 170px;">
            <col style="width: 230px;">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tbHead">Name</td>
                <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payEmployee" id="payEmployee" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td class="tbHead">Payment Date</td>
                <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payDisDate" id="payDisDate" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tbHead">Working Duration</td>
                <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payDuration" id="payDuration" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                <td class="tbHead">Currency Rate (R/USD)</td>
                <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payRate" id="payRate" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="paytblparent">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 400px;">
        <col style="width: 400px;">
    </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="paytblhalf" style="margin:20px 0 30px 0;">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 170px;">
                        <col style="width: 228px;">
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tbHead">Basic Salary</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                                <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payBasicSalary" id="payBasicSalary" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trOT" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbHead">OT</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                                <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payOT" id="payOT" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trSpecial" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbHead">Special Allowance</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                                <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="paySpecialAllowance" id="paySpecialAllowance" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trAllowance" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbHead">Allowance</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payAllowance" id="payAllowance" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trRetroactivity" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbHead">Retroactivity</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payRetroactivity" id="payRetroactivity" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trAnnual" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbHead">Annual Leave</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payAnnualLeave" id="payAnnualLeave" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trBAdvanced" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbHead">Advanced</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payBAdvanced" id="payBAdvanced" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trBReturnAdv" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbHead">Returned Advance</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payBReturnAdv" id="payBReturnAdv" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tbHead" rowspan="2">Family Allowance</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p style="display:inline;">Spouse:</p><p style="display:inline;"></p>
                            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="paySpouse" id="paySpouse" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trFamily">
                            <td class="tbContent"><p style="display:inline;">Children:</p><p style="display:inline;"></p>
                            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payChildren" id="payChildren" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tbHead">Payroll Amount</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                                <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payTotal" id="payTotal" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trThank">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Thank You!</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="paytblright" style="margin:20px 0 30px 0;">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 170px;">
                        <col style="width: 228px;">
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tbHead">Tax on Salary</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                                <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payTax" id="payTax" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tbHead">Advanced (S.A.)</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                                <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payAAdvanced" id="payAAdvanced" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="zeroZero" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="zeroOne" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="zeroTwo" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="zeroThree" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="zeroFour" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="zeroFive" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="zeroSix" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="zeroSeven" style="display:none;">
                            <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tbHead">Deductible Amount</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                                <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payDeductible" id="payDeductible" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tbHead">Payable Amount</td>
                            <td class="tbContent"><p></p>
                                <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="payNet" id="payNet" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JavaScript

```
bindEvent : function(){
    $(".btnPrintPay").on('click', function(){
        $("#printArea").printThis({
            debug: false,
            importCSS: true,
            importStyle: true,
            printContainer: true,
            removeInline: false,
            printDelay: 333,
            header: null,
            formValues: true
        });
    });
```

CSS

```
.paytbl { width: 800px; display: table; background: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse;}
.paytbl td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 36px; border-style: solid; border: 2px solid black;}
.paytbl td.tbHead { background: #E8E8E8; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 36px; border-style: solid; border: 2px solid black;}
.paytbl td.tbContentTwo { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px; height: 200px; border-style: solid; border: 2px solid black;}
.paytbl td.tbText { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; }
.paytbl td.tbBody { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 7px 0 0 7px; height: 200px; vertical-align: text-top; }

.paytblparent { border-collapse: collapse; }

.paytblhalf { width: 400px; display: table; background: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; float: right}
.paytblhalf td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 36px; border-style: solid; border: 2px solid black;}
.paytblhalf td.tbHead { background: #E8E8E8; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 36px; border-style: solid; border: 2px solid black;}
.paytblhalf td.tbContentTwo { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px; height: 200px; border-style: solid; border: 2px solid black;}
.paytblhalf td.tbText { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; }
.paytblhalf td.tbBody { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 7px 0 0 7px; height: 200px; vertical-align: text-top; }
.paytblhalf tr#trThank td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 36px; border-style: solid;}

.paytblright { width: 400px; display: table; background: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; float: left}
.paytblright td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 36px; border-style: solid; border: 2px solid black;}
.paytblright td.tbHead { background: #E8E8E8; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 36px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
.paytblright td.tbContentTwo { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px; height: 200px; border-style: solid; border: 2px solid black;}
.paytblright td.tbText { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; }
.paytblright td.tbBody { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 7px 0 0 7px; height: 200px; vertical-align: text-top; }

.paytblright tr#zeroZero td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 36px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
.paytblright tr#zeroOne td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 74px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
.paytblright tr#zeroTwo td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 112px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
.paytblright tr#zeroThree td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 150px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
.paytblright tr#zeroFour td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 188px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
.paytblright tr#zeroFive td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 226px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
.paytblright tr#zeroSix td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 264px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
.paytblright tr#zeroSeven td.tbContent { background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0 7px 0 7px; height: 302px; border-style: solid solid solid hidden;}
```

Comment: Oh god. Printing and pdf generation is a pain in the butt. I worked on something a while ago that had dynamically generated content that needed to be gorgeous, otherwise it was no good, and that's about the time I started balding. You gotta do some research on proper stylings that can and should be used for printing. Recommended printing layout. It looks like one page but to use page-break and friends css attributes.

Comment: I'm the author of printThis. This layout is complicated due to the nested tables, and the hidden table rows in the right nested table. Although you could probably fix the layout for one browser, my guess is that this issue varies across browsers.

Instead of hidden table rows to achieve the large blank cell, have you tried using `rowspan`? That might achieve a more uniform result.